# How can I use a dynamic matrix as a parameter, of a function, in C++?

Tags: c++, function, image-processing, parameters, parameter-passing

I'm reading a bmp image. So my matrix is dynamic. I'm learning its columns and rows size in runtime. I want to use this dynamic matrix as a parameter of a function.

`func(w,h, inMatrix, outMatrix);`

I want to call my function like this.

```
void func(int w,int h,?,?)
{
....
    outMatrix[x][y].R=inMatrix[x][y].R*someThing;
....
}
```

How can I define this function?

So ?=?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Simply pass array name to function, and receive in double array. For example void func1(char array[][]){} will be function defintion

Comment: You will call the function as func1(arr); arr is double array

Answer (score 1):

Use a pointer to an object that wraps that behaviour? or use a reference to the matrix. I would avoid passing by copy due to performance issues.

Comment: Or ditch the pointer and use the matrix directly (or by reference). Using a pointer is almost certainly a bad solution here.

Comment: I wouldn't use it directly by copy, best solution would be by reference yes.